# How do I change the initial view controller with a PFUser?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to avoid the start/login screen overall and go straight to the first page of the app if the user is logged in. Nothing happens when I run the code below. I breakpointed, and it said that the current user is nil, but when the view loads, the current user is not nil.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    print("user \(currentUser)")
    if currentUser != nil {
        if(currentUser?.username?.rangeOfString("@music.co") != nil){
           self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("venuehomescreen")
        }else{
            self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("userhomescreen")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually proceed as normal in my application to the log in view controller, than in viewDidAppear of that log in view controller, I add logic similar to the following:

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil{
    //perform segue
    //or present view controller modally
}
```

It's important to have your log in view controller in the heiarchy for cases such as logging out which enables you to just unwind to the log in view controller.

Also, it's necessary to perform a segue in viewDidAppear because you must perform view controller transitions only after the view controller you're transitioning from has been added to the heiarchy.

Comment: This is what I am doing right now, but I don't want the user to always click the login button to perform the segue. Instead right after the loading screen it automatically goes to the home screen.

Comment: but if it's in viewDidAppear in your initial view controller to your application (log in view controller), it requires nothing from your user. The app will proceed to log the user in if one is cached

Comment: Yeah that is what's happening, but I get a glimpse of the login page before it proceeds to the home screen, is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: your way as illustrated should work. The key thing is you must initialize Parse first before you check for PFUser so Parse.setApplicationId....